# Double Declining Balance In C#

Tags: c#

So I need to create a method where I input years and amount and the console program will output a chart that shows the  double-declining balance depreciation.

This is what I have.

```
 static void doubleDecliningBalance(double amount, int years)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,10}", "Year", "Depreciation");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");            
        int count = 0;
        double depreciation, amountLeft = 0;


        while (count < years)
        {
            amountLeft = amount;
            count = count + 1;                
            depreciation = (amountLeft * (2 / years));
            amountLeft = amount - depreciation;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,10:C2}", count, amountLeft);
        }
    }
```

Now when I run the program it won't depreciate. The formula is correct I think so I'm confused to why it won't depreciate, which means if I enter 5 years and a amount of $5000; it will just show 5000 for all 5 years.

Comment: you are never updating `amount`, so your output will be the same each loop.

Comment: This would be a perfect time to learn to use the debugger to step through your code, which would have shown you the problem in two or three passes through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting from the original amount each iteration of the loop, which means that you do not depreciate from the current balance at each year, but from the starting balance.

If `amount` represents the original amount and `amountLeft` represents the current balance, try changing the loop into something like this

```
amountLeft = amount;
while (count < years)
{
    count = count + 1;                
    depreciation = (amountLeft * (2.0 / years));
    amountLeft -= depreciation;
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,10:C2}", count, amountLeft);
}
```

Edit: As @Jim pointed out, there is another error with your code. Because you added parantheses around `(2 / years)` the depreciation will likely be zero (i.e. unless years is 1 or 2), due to the calculating being done as integer division. Either remove parantheses or let the `2` be a floating point value.

Comment: That's part of the fix. There are two lines that set `amountLeft` in the loop; both of them need to be addressed.

Comment: @DStanley, True. I did not see that the same variable was being reassigned. Answer updated.

Comment: And now the OP is wondering why it's still 5000 on all lines :)